# How to use Linq to query a tuple like the way to query an array in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var primes = Tuple.Create(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13);
        var primes2 = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13};

        var results = primes2.Where(p => p > 3);

        foreach (int p in results)
            Console.WriteLine(p);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The code above runs well as it is a simple way to query an array with Linq. However, when I tried to change from

```
    var results = primes2.Where(p => p > 3);
```

into

```
    var results = primes.Where(p => p > 3);
```

the code wouldn't compile because it reports there is no Where defined for tuple type like that for array type. Is there a way to work around it so that we can query a tuple using linq just like we query an array using linq?

Comment: Well, a tuple is not a *collection* of items, it´s a *single* item. Why should there be any filter-method?

Answer (score 3):

`Tuple` represents an object, not a collection. `Where` is an extension method for the `IEnumerable<TSource>` interface which is used by collections, so  you can't call `Where` on a `Tuple` object.

You have to use a collection, which implements `IEnumerable<TSource>`, to carry `Tuple` object data.

```
var primes = Tuple.Create(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13);
List<int> primes_li = new List<int>()
{
    primes.Item1,
    primes.Item2,
    primes.Item3,
    primes.Item4,
    primes.Item5,
    primes.Item6
};
var results = primes_li.Where(p => p > 3);
```

Or use reflection to get all item values by `GetProperties` method from `Tuple` object.

```
var primes = Tuple.Create(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13);

var results = primes.GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .Select(x => (int)x.GetValue(primes))
    .Where(p => p > 3);
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AAQItD)

**Result**

```
5
7
11
13
```